# ES6: What happens if the rest parameter is an array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

if I have:

```
function foo(number, ...args) {
   //foo to add args to sum
}
```

and I want a caller to be able to call foo like:

```
foo(10, 1, 2, 3); // 16
```

or:

```
foo(10, [1, 2, 3]); //16
```

The question is how to implement this.
Can I do this:

```
function foo(number, ...args) {
    let toAddArr = Array.isArray(args[0]) ? args[0] : args;
    for (let toAdd of toAddArr) {
        number = number + toAdd;
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: do you always want only add the numbers?

Comment: That looks fine.  Did you try it?

Comment: @webduvet just an example, I am writing an entirely different function in which args can be arguments or an array

Comment: @RocketHazmat Not yet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use some recursion:

```
function foo(...args) {
    var sum = 0;
    args.forEach((arg) => {
        if (!Array.isArray(arg))
            sum += arg
        else
            sum += foo(...arg); // if it's an array, destructure
    });
    return sum;
}
```

With that code, you can even pass arrays inside arrays inside arrays if you want :)

Edit, with a `for` loop:

```
function foo(...args) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var arg of args) {
        if (!Array.isArray(arg))
            sum += arg
        else
            sum += foo(...arg); // if it's an array, destructure
    };
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: I dont understand the (arg) => {} syntax, I mean I know it is an arrow function but I don't understand how you are using it.

Comment: It's just the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function of `Array`, I prefer to use that instead of a `for` loop but it does the same thing. I added a `for` version so you can the difference, not much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.concat` with `.apply`, and for sum `.reduce`, like this

```
function foo(...args) {
  return ([].concat.apply([], args)).reduce(function (prev, curr) {
    return prev + curr;
  }, 0);
}
```

[`Example`](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20foo(...args)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20(%5B%5D.concat.apply(%5B%5D%2C%20args)).reduce(function%20(prev%2C%20curr)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20prev%20%2B%20curr%3B%0A%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(%0A%20%20foo(10%2C%201%2C%202%2C%203)%0A)%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(%0A%20%20foo(10%2C%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D)%0A)%3B)

Answer (score 1):

Well you can convert the arguments to an array and concat them.

```js
function foo(){
   return [].concat.apply([],Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)).reduce( function (p,c) { return p + c; }, 0);
}
var x1 = foo(10, [1,2,3]);
console.log(x1);

var x2 = foo(10,1,2,3);
console.log(x2);
```

Comment: You can use `[].slice.call(arguments)` instead of `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`

Comment: How does the Array.prototype.slice(arguments) work if arguments = 10, [1, 2, 3]? Isn't call expecting arguments instead of array?

Comment: arguments is not an array so it converts it to an array so I can run array methods against it. The concat line than collapses the array (if there is one).

Answer (score 0):

for nested arrays recursion might work nicely. You can have only numbers or arrays or nested arrays or mixed.

```
  function add() {
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function(p, c) {
      if (Array.isArray(c)) {
        return p + add.apply(null, c);
      } else {
        return p + c;
      }
    });
  }
```