# Sum all integers in a multidimensional array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, sum

Let's say I have this:

```
function arrSum(){
  *code here*
}
```

How do I write the arrSum function such that it can sum all the integers within a multidimensional array (of variable depth).

I.e.

```
arrSum([2, 5, [4, 6], 5]) === 22;
```

I know there must be an answer to this somewhere but I really can't find it. If this is a duplicate please let me know.

Comment: There is an anwser but using ES6: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33306533/5388620 It's almost the same answer as below and uses recursion too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply you can write a function like this with recursion

```js
function arrSum(arr) {
  var sum = 0;
  // iterate array using forEach, better to use for loop since it have higher performance
  arr.forEach(function(v) {
    // checking array element is an array
    if (typeof v == 'object')
      // if array then getting sum it's element (recursion)
      sum += arrSum(v);
    else
      // else adding the value with sum
      sum += v
  })
  // returning the result
  return sum;
}

console.log(arrSum([2, 5, [4, 6], 5]) === 22);
```

Using `for` loop

```js
function arrSum(arr) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (typeof arr[i] == 'object')
      sum += arrSum(arr[i]);
    else
      sum += arr[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(arrSum([2, 5, [4, 6], 5]) === 22);
```

Comment: This works perfectly - thank you.

Can I just ask - why are you testing for typeof object?

Comment: @VoA : checking inner element is `array` or `number`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: I would just move the **isObject** check before the `foreach`, that way, sending a single numeric, it will still work.

Comment: In your for loop answer you wrote: "sum += arrSum(arr[i]);". Could you explain what this is doing? Is it calling the arrSum function from within itself?

Comment: @VoA :  calling the same function with inner array ( recursion ), and adding return value with `sum` variable

Answer (score 5):

A more modern approach using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const arr = [2, 5, [4, 6], 5];

const arrSum = array =>
    array.reduce(
        (sum, num) => sum + (Array.isArray(num) ? arrSum(num) : num * 1),
        0
    );

console.log(arrSum(arr));
```

Answer (score 5):

Why is no one using `flat()`?

```js
const arr = [2, 5, [4, 6], 5];

const result = arr.flat().reduce((a,b) => a+b);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
function arrSum(objArr){
  var total = 0;
  for(var outerLoop=0; outerLoop < objArr.length; outerLoop++){
    if(objArr[outerLoop].constructor === Array){
      for(var innerLoop=0; innerLoop < objArr[outerLoop].length; innerLoop++){
        total += objArr[outerLoop][innerLoop];
      }
    } else {
      total += objArr[outerLoop];
    }
  }
  return total;
}

alert (arrSum([2, 5, [4, 6], 5]));
```

Comment: OP said of variable array depth. This will only go two deep.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function arrSum(arr) {
        var totalSum = null;
        var numString = arr.toString();
        var numberArray = numString.split(",");
        numberArray.forEach(function(ele){
          totalSum = totalSum + parseInt(ele);
        });
        return totalSum;
    }
    console.log(arrSum([2, 5, [4, 6], 5]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If we have a multi-dimensional array with strings and integers and we have to get the sum of the numbers, then following @Pranav C Balan's solution we could add a check in the else loop to check only for digits as below -

```js
      function arrSum(arr) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (typeof arr[i] == 'object'){
         sum += arrSum(arr[i]);
      }else if (Number(arr[i])){
         sum += arr[i];
      }
    }
    return sum;
  }
  console.log(arrSum([2, 'a', 5, [4, 6, 10, [1, 2, 'b'], 10], 5]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would build a function similar to what *Pranav C Balan* with the difference that i would check the `isObject()` before calling `forEach()`,
This way i get around problems posed by sending a single *`numeric`* parameter, or `Null` values.

```js
function arrSum(v) {
  // checking if element is an array
  if (typeof v == 'object') {
    var sum = 0;
    
    // iterate array using forEach, better to use for loop since it have higher performance
    v.forEach(function(e) {
      sum+=arrSum(e);
    });
    return sum;
  }
  else {
      return v;
  }
}
$('body').append($('<p></p>').html('[2, 5, [4, 6], 5] = ' + arrSum([2, 5, [4, 6], 5])));
$('body').append($('<p></p>').html('[2,, 5] = ' + arrSum([2,, 5])));
$('body').append($('<p></p>').html('5 = ' + arrSum(5)));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with lodash [`_.flattenDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flattenDeep) and [`_.sum`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#sum):

```js
var arr = [2, 5, [4, 6], 5];
arrSum(arr);

function arrSum(arr) {
  var arrFlattens = _.flattenDeep(arr);
  // => [2, 5, 4, 6, 5]
  console.log(_.sum(arrFlattens));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [@zeh](https://stackoverflow.com/u/9319353)'s answer to include a check for number and convert a string to a number:

```
function arrSum(arr) {
  const sum = arr.flat().map(a => +a).filter(a => typeof a === "number" && !isNaN(a)).reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);
  return sum;
}
```

Below is a breakdown of the code using an example 3D array - flat() depth set to 2.

```js
const array3d  = [[2, '8', 5], [[4, 6], 10],[1, 2, 'b'],[10, 5, 'f']];

function arrSumBreakdown(arr) {
  // change any number strings to numbers
  const allnum   = arr.flat(2).map(a => +a);
  console.log('flat & convert to numbers: ',...allnum);
  // keep only numbers and remove NaN
  const numonly  = allnum.filter(a => typeof a === "number" && !isNaN(a));
  console.log('remove NaN:',...numonly);
  // sum array
  const sumnum   = numonly.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);
  return sumnum;
}

console.log('sum array:',arrSumBreakdown(array3d));

// all in one
function arrSum(arr) {
  const sum = arr.flat(2).map(a => +a).filter(a => typeof a === "number" && !isNaN(a)).reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);
  return sum;
}

console.log('combine all elements (sum array):',arrSum(array3d));
```

references:

- [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- [convert into a number (unary operator)](https://medium.com/@nikjohn/cast-to-number-in-javascript-using-the-unary-operator-f4ca67c792ce)
- [typeof()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)
- [Why does typeof NaN return 'number'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801601/why-does-typeof-nan-return-number)